# Get value from object by key in java

Tags: java, json, reflection, entitymanager, jsonparser

I am getting object in the response of `entityManager.find` method.
and i want to get values from that object by passing key. but i din't get any success.

For example :-

my entity :-

```
@entity
class Test (){
public Long id;
public String name ;
public String descr;
}
```

and i am getting object in the response of below code.

```
`Object obj=`entitymanager.find(classname,id);
```

Note :- Instead of object i can't use entity's object directly because input class name can be dynamically pass that's why i am taking response in Object.

Now i want to get value from object by passing key
something like that   `obj.getvalue("id");`

I tried below things to make it done :-

1. `Map<String, Object> user = (Map<String, Object>)obj;`
2. Used json simple parser to parse it.

   `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();`

   JSONObject jsonObject =parser.parse(obj.toString());

But din't get any success.

Please help me out.

Comment: Arent you able to cast the object to it's actual class? Since you provide the classname you should know to which class you can cast.

Comment: @Sebastian  i mentioned 'Test' entity just for the example , i can pass classname dynamically in find method , that's the problem i have more than 100 entity and i can pass entity name dynamically

Comment: If you pass the classname dynamically, how would you know whether the returned object has the desired field?

Comment: @Sebastian   Before getting values  by key ,first i am getting all the list of fields using REFLECTION api  then passing those fields.
Thanks for your feedback :) 
i am able to resolved the issue by using reflection and object mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what you're asking... but as long as "name" is a primary key you can call

```
Test obj = entitymanager.find(Test.class, name);
```

Comment: I am passing entity name dynamically in find method , i have more than 100 entity in my project and i am getting entity name as input and passing that entity name in FIND  method. thats why i want to access value from Object

Comment: Edted answer. .

Comment: Thanks for the response. i think you din't get my question correctly.
i am able to solve my issue by using objectmapper

Answer (score -1):

`Object obj=`entitymanager.find(classname,id);

In the above line what is the type of "classname".
Since your question does not mention the type. I assume its of type Object.
You should do something like

`Object obj=`entitymanager.find(classname.getClass(),id);